# Google Maps in Ionic-angular application is loading in localhost but not when deployed to firebase

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, firebase, ionic-framework

I have an application which is using ionic angular framework, in which I have integrated google maps functionality.The issue is that google maps functionality is working properly in localhost but not loading when deployed to firebase.
I have also tried with ngMaps but could see this same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

My site was loaded over https,but was requesting an insecure script *http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key =xxxxxxxx&sensor=true*
When used the below script in my application, the issue was resolved
*https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key =xxxxxxxx&sensor=true*